# How do I increase my processing speed?

Tags: intelligence, iq

I have an IQ of around 90 (with 88 of that as reasoning IQ and 92 as performance IQ). I’m extremely worried about getting a job and doing well. Are there any exercises, medication, lifestyle changes and the like that can get me to increase my processing speed in the context of workplace performance? I personally was thinking of a combination between exercise, the Dual-N-Back program, stimulants, and a ketogenic diet.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE! I am sorry, but [for a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-was-my-self-help-question-closed-as-off-topic) we can not, and will not, give advice or potential diagnoses for any specific individual. If you or anyone else has a question regarding personal mental health, advice from a doctor should be sought. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta].

Comment: Processing speed is very largely about practice. Something new will take more concerted effort. Something well practised will become more second-nature and automatic. Think about language or maths. When we are first learning them, it can take forever. But then it gets easier.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.